# Unity update movement vector. Phisical meaning of vector values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to understand the phisical meaning of the example from the book "Unity in action" from the end of 2nd chapter. In this code object is moving to the "delta" Vector3 in frame. Is Vector3 here a speed vector in point? If it is, why author used gravity variable with the value of acceleration of gravity (9.8) in same vector?

```cs
public class FPSInput : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 6.0f;
    public float gravity = -9.8f;
    private CharacterController _charController;

    void Start() {
        _charController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update() {
        float deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        float deltaZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(deltaX, 0, deltaZ);
        movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, speed);
        movement.y = gravity;
        movement *= Time.deltaTime;
        movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);
        _charController.Move(movement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector3 movement is a vector of difference in movement of character in one frame (Update) of the game.

So to move, he first takes user controls for X and Z axis, multiplies them by speed.

Then you need to apply gravity because without it you'll be flying anywhere you want instead of walking, so you need to apply gravity for vertical axis Y. "9.8" is a standard gravity on earth.

Then you need to multiply everything (this movement vector) by delta time, which represents the time that took the frame to update and render. Without delta time you will have different results with different frame rates.

And then he apply's the "movement" vector (as I said a difference in movement in one frame) to the current position of character.

Comment: I understand, I don't understand units of measure at each stage of calculating. If user press forward, which value user control is? One? Is it scalar? Ok, Time.deltaTime is time. We can multiply speed and time. We get delta distance. But why he did movement.y = gravity , where movement is speed vector?

Comment: If you press forward - you'll go "speed" distance in one second (in current example 6). And "gravity" distance (-9.8) in vertical axis in one second too (like in real life). Gravity is simply set to vertical axis because you can't control gravity with your movement. Like in real life, you're always walking in 2 directions, and gravity (vertical) force is always the same. It would need to differ only if you'll implement the "Jump" feature, which is not in this example.

Comment: O, understand: speed=gt. t=1 second. Ok.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kind of moving an object in unity

1. Add a force to unit and push it move
2. Set unit position every time elapsed (also called slide unit)

In your case, it is type 2 thus your `Vector3` movement indicate position of moving unit.

In your code, movement is calculated by multiple `Input.GetAxis()` (value range: [0, 1]) with speed value, then take the max distance an interval that unit can move by `movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, speed);`.
It just for unit move on the ground (left, right, forward, backward)

Next is for unit height, movement apply y axis equal to gravity value (9,8) multiple with deltaTime. It mean every 1 second unit height will reduced by 9.8

After all, convert `movement` from local to world then set position of moving unit by `movement`.

Hope my answer can solve your issue.

Comment: I'l check code tomorrow in mono develop and will experiment with params. Now just read. Thank you.